# Empty the Cart items but keep the quote and quote items

Tags: magento2, cart, quote

I have added a button on cart page. Clicking on the button the cart items should get deleted but the quote should not be erased.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. We have to set the quote to inactive.

```
$quote->setIsActive(0);
$quote->save();
```